# firebase storage cors. IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'cors-json-file.json'

Tags: firebase, cors, google-cloud-sdk

I'm familiar with firebase and fire storage, but new to G-Cloud-SDK.  I found this topic https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/oSPWMS7MSNA/RnvU6aqtFwAJ and tried to copy the results, but get "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'cors-json-file.json'" from the terminal.

I found a bit more information in the docs https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-gsutil and it describes the same process, and I get the same error.

I'm finding it hard to do any troubleshooting with Google Cloud SDK since I have already setup functions in Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://example-bucket
```

Example: If the cors.json file in the d: drive then the path will be like
d:/folderName/cors_filename. The gs url is your bucket url.

Comment: In addition, to use the command copied from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files, you'd have to put the cors.json file inside your home directory. ie. "~/"

Comment: In addition, to use the command copied from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files, you'd have to put the cors.json file inside your home directory. ie. "~/"

Answer (score 0):

I did not move my local directory to my 'cors-json-file.json' ...